# Sql Server 2012 (T-SQL) String Comparison (for equality) gives asterisk in query results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, string-comparison

I am comparing two strings from different tables for equality using:

```
WHERE OMRBuildingSurveys.PublishedOwner != OwnershipEntities.Name
```

I want to exclude all results where the two strings are equal in my query results. However, where the strings are equal they are still being displayed but for some reason there is an asterisk in the query results as you can see in the results shown here

```
PublishedOwner          Owner Name
Seymour Developments    Unknown
Westpac Bank            Westpac Bank *
```

I have tried casting both strings to varchars and nvarchars and it doesn't seem to affect the results.

If anyone could tell me what I'm missing. I'd be hugely grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this.

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3
FROM OMRBuildingSurveys 
WHERE OMRBuildingSurveys.PublishedOwner NOT IN 
                                              (
                                               SELECT OwnershipEntities.Name 
                                               FROM  OwnershipEntities
                                               )
```

Comment: Thanks so much Muhammed! (Great user name by the way). I've actually discovered (by using your method) that the problem was not my first query but that somehow the astersisk "*" has been added to the data in the table so the first query works fine. Thanks again!

Comment: not a problem mate but its not just my user name it is my REAL NAME :)